# PHP/SQL - Nested statements?

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to select rows from a table, and use those results to update another table. So I think I need nested SQL statements.

This is my code so far:

```
<?
    //DB Connection
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    //Get all entries
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                //Set Variables
                $userid = $row['uid'];

                //Now for every result in here, I want to increase the entries column for this user in a different table    
                $sql_2 = "UPDATE user SET entires = entries +1 WHERE uid=".$userid;
                $result_2 = $conn_2->query($sql_2);

                if ($conn_2->query($sql_2) === TRUE) {
                    echo "Record updated successfully";
                } else {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn_2->error;
                }   

            }

    }
?>
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
The answer worked to an extent... But I want to do a calculation, based on a column in the entries table, before updating the user table.

I have a type column in entries, with possible values as sale, support etc...

sales is with 10 points, and support is worth 1 point

I want this reflected in the 'entries' column in the user table.

Is this possible?

Comment: `entires` != `entries`

Comment: @u_mulder, SQL has `<>`, not `!=`...

Comment: @jarlh case is that OP uses __different__ field names on the left and on the right.

Comment: you can do that in a single query rather than loops and nested queries I think like `UPDATE user SET entries = entries+1 WHERE uid in ( SELECT uid FROM entries ) `?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have good reason to need a `nested query` running in the loop then it makes sense to do the entire update operation in the database with a single query.

Given a very basic assumed schema for the above sql commands

```
mysql> describe user;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username | varchar(50)      | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| entries  | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe entries;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And then basic provisioning of some test users

```
insert into `user` ( `username` ) values ( 'Bobby' );
insert into `entries` ( `uid` ) values ( last_insert_id() );

insert into `user` ( `username` ) values ( 'George' );
insert into `entries` ( `uid` ) values ( last_insert_id() );

insert into `user` ( `username` ) values ( 'Racquel' );
insert into `entries` ( `uid` ) values ( last_insert_id() );

mysql> select * from user;
+-----+----------+---------+
| uid | username | entries |
+-----+----------+---------+
|   1 | Bobby    |       0 |
|   2 | George   |       0 |
|   3 | Racquel  |       0 |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

When you need to run the update for all users a single query that selects the user's `uid` for use in the where clause should work ok.

```
update `user` set `entries`=`entries`+1 where `uid` in ( select `uid` from `entries` );
```

After running the above a few times

```
mysql> select * from user;
+-----+----------+---------+
| uid | username | entries |
+-----+----------+---------+
|   1 | Bobby    |      13 |
|   2 | George   |      13 |
|   3 | Racquel  |      13 |
+-----+----------+---------+

mysql> select * from entries;
+----+-----+
| id | uid |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   1 |
|  2 |   2 |
|  3 |   3 |
+----+-----+
```